# Visual Studio Memory Analyser - finding the source for "path to root"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-management

I've got a memory leak, I found it via an event listener (a weak reference one!) still firing for something I thought had been deleted, so I can get a breakpoint in the actual class instance that should have been garbage collected.

Is there any way I can find what variables are referencing a specific instance in debug?

I've tried using the memory profiler, and the offending instance is shown there:

[image]

It even shows the "path to root", which I believe are the references that are keeping this object alive?

However, it doesn't actually provide me with any information beyond telling me it's a "local variable", right clicking and pressing "Go to definition" or "Go to source" perform no actions.

Does anyone know of a way I can find out what this reference actually is so I can deal with it?

Comment: did you also run some static code analyse and resolved them?

Comment: What kind of static code analyse?

Comment: VS has built in one. right click your project-then menu

Comment: There's a bunch of warnings that have come up, thanks I didn't know about that tool. I'll work through them and see if it's found the issue causing the leak.

Comment: often it is better to solve static analyze warnings first. your points are higher and i though you should know it

Comment: Definitely looks like a good thing to know, I'd previously used the complexity analysis tools but didn't know about this one. Thanks for telling me about it.

Comment: I can't seem to find a static code analysis tool in visual studio 2019. Can you please guide?